# when 2nd javascript is called by 1st javascript , it is not getting executed

Tags: javascript, html

Following is my code. The issue is , the 2nd javascript [changeText(i)]is not getting executed when it is called by 1st javascript [changeImage(i)] 
(I tried it in firefox and chrome.). I think even the call for the script changeText(i) is not executing. Can you help me to find out the above stated problem? what might be the reason behind changeText(i) is not executing?

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Menu</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeText(i)
                {

                        switch(i)
                                    {
                            case 'a':   document.getElementById('hed').innerHTML = "Previous Month"+ <?php echo "hai"; ?> ;

                                                break;
                            case 'b':  document.getElementById('hed').innerHTML = "You pressed " + <?php echo "hai"; ?> + i;
                                                break;

                            default: return false;
                        }

        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeImage(i) {

        var img = document.getElementById("img");

        switch (i) {
          case 'a':
            img.src = "graph_bar.php";
            changeText(i);
            break;
          case 'b':
            img.src = "graph_bar1.php";changeText(i);
            break;
          default:
            return false;
        }
      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <div align="center">

      <input type="button" value="Previous-Day" onclick="changeImage('a');" />&nbsp &nbsp
      <input type="button" value="Previous-Month" onclick="changeImage('b');" />



    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Type of Index: <strong id="hed"> </strong></th>
        <th>

        </th>

      </tr>


    </table>
    <div>

    <img id="img">

    </div>

    </div>

  </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Load your second javascript before first gets loaded

Comment: Your code works as expected for me. Try checking your browser console for errors.

Comment: @amoeba why? That is not going to make a difference in this case...

Comment: DO you expect it to be called for `b` when you do not even call it for `b`?

Comment: @epascarello, 
i have mentioned about case a. i am aware that there is no call for case b. –

Comment: Well the code runs so what is different with the code above and what you have? Are there errors in your browser's console?

Comment: @epascarello, i am not getting any error. i tried to debug it, and the code executes before the call changeText(i), then no response.

Comment: Is the code in your question the exact code you are running that is not working. Because the code in your question works.

Comment: @epascarello,  this is not the exact code, i have some php variables displayed in changeText(i). i think that is the issue. It is working fine without php variable. i have updated the code in question.

Comment: And when you view the source of the page you will see you have invalid syntax and you should have an error in your console.

Comment: @epascarello, i can see the value of php variables, when i view source of the page.That is the irony here.But  it is not executing through javascript.

Comment: My answer tells you why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now that you showed what is actually happening with the edit, you can see your PHP is causing a syntax error

```
"You pressed " + <?php echo "hai"; ?> + i;
```

will produce

```
"You pressed " + hai + i;
```

and I doubt you have a javascript variable `hai`. It needs to be quoted. Look into using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output the string.

Comment: i replaced php variable with string "hai" as example. But even that hai is not displayed through javascript. basically when there is php variable or string as shown in the updated code in question, it is not executed.

Comment: because it needs to be wrapped in quotes with JavaScript. Look at using json_encode in your echo statement. `<?php echo json_encode("hai") ?>;`

Answer (score 1):

your change text is not executing in case b because you didn't call the function over there.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Menu</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeText(i) {
        document.getElementById('hed').innerHTML = "Previous Month";
        switch (i) {
          case 'a':
            document.getElementById('hed').innerHTML = "Previous Month";
            break;
          case 'b':
            document.getElementById('hed').innerHTML = "You pressed " + i;
            break;

          default:
            return false;
        }

      }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeImage(i) {

        var img = document.getElementById("img");

        switch (i) {
          case 'a':
            img.src = "https://placeimg.com/300/100/animal";
            changeText(i);
            break;
          case 'b':
            img.src = "https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech";
   changeText(i);
            break;
          default:
            return false;
        }
      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <div align="center">

      <input type="button" value="Previous-Day" onclick="changeImage('a');" />&nbsp &nbsp
      <input type="button" value="Previous-Month" onclick="changeImage('b');" />

    </div>

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Type of Index: <strong id="hed"> </strong></th>
        <th>

        </th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Master Id : <strong id="hed1"> </strong></td>

      </tr>

    </table>
    </div>

    <img id="img">

    </div>

    </div>

  </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: i have mentioned about case a. i am aware that there is no call for case b.

Comment: I am sorry man but i didn't see anything regarding case. your code is totally good man.